# How do I populate values for multiple chosen plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am using a jQuery plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and I am having trouble populating selected values into the textbox.

Based on the options page, it says
$('.my_select_box').trigger('chosen:updated');

However I do have multiple select boxes, say

```
<select id="select1" class="chzn-select" name="select1" data-placeholder="Choose an employee..." multiple="true" style="width: 350px; display: none;"></select>

<select id="select2" class="chzn-select" name="select2" data-placeholder="Choose an employee..." multiple="true" style="width: 350px; display: none;"></select>

<select id="select3" class="chzn-select" name="select3" data-placeholder="Choose an employee..." multiple="true" style="width: 350px; display: none;"></select>
```

and in my jQuery script I do have

```
$('.chzn-select', this).chosen(); // do I use this to prepopulate?
```

but if I had already selected values into the 3 select boxes, how do I populate back the values again?

I have a function that saves them into the database though:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){

    var firstVal= $("#select1").val();
    var secondVal= $("#select2").val();
    var thirdVal = $("#select3").val();

     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "myPoST",
        data: {
            firstVal:firstVal,
            secondVal :secondVal,
            thirdVal :thirdVal;
        },
        ....// what do I do here?
      });
  });
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Desired output when page is loaded:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add selected attribute in your option tag, [see example here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#selected-and-disabled-support)

In your html:

```
<select id="ddlCarList" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes" selected="selected">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi" selected="selected">Audi</option>
</select>
```

in javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#ddlCarList").chosen();
});
</script>
```

[check demo here](http://jsbin.com/memub/1/edit)